# How to stop processing external javascript file?

Tags: javascript

In my scenario, some javascript file is going to be attached to all svg files on our site. However depending on some conditions it should not always be processed. How can i achieve this, since I cannot use (at the beginning of file):

```
if (!condition) return;
```

I know I can do opposite:

```
if (condition) {
    /* some code */
}
```

but It would be easier to simply stop processing file then adding unnecessary block.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about how this JavaScript file works? You could always write the script in a way that it doesn't do anything until you call a specific function.

Comment: "since I cannot use" — Why not?

Comment: @Quentin because of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement`

Comment: @Halcyon and that's sound like a nice solution, why I haven't thought about that? I knew it was simple. Thx.